# try/catch block doesn't work when Model's id is unexpected

Tags: php, laravel, exception, model

here's my code:

```
$id = 'wrong id';
try{
    $myLaravelModel = MyLaravelModel::find($id);
    $myLaravelModel->done = true; //here's error      
}catch (Exception $e){
    return 'error';
}
```

and when the code gets to the line with comment, I got error: "Creating default object from empty value", which is accurate, but I thought the catch block would catch that and return 'error'. Why is it not working?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message? Is this even related to an **exception**?

Comment: @NicoHaase When you try to assign a property to `null`, i.e. using `$myLaravelModel->done = true;`, it throws an error "ErrorException: Creating default object from empty value." Note this error is Laravel specific; this is a `Warning` in base php. That being said, I can't recreate this issue. My `try { ... } catch(){ ... }` handles this case just fine.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use findOrFail(). `MyLaravelModel::findOrFail($id)`. 
As it was said in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

> Not Found Exceptions
>
> Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found.
>   This is particularly useful in routes or controllers. The `findOrFail`
>   and `firstOrFail` methods will retrieve the first result of the query;
>   however, if no result is found, a
>   `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown: